# SUM of all elements of a two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to solve a challenge from jshero.net. The challenge is:

> Write a function sum that calculates the sum of all elements of a
> two-dimensional array. sum([[1, 2], [3]]) should return 6.
> For this one I need to use a nested loop. The best solution I could come up with is:

```
function sum(num){
let mySum= [num.length]
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i > mySum; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j > mySum; j++) {
    sum =mySum[[i]+[j]];
  }
}
}
```

But when I run the code I get the following error:

> sum([[1]]) does not return 1, but undefined.
>
> Test-Error! Correct the error and re-run the tests!

Do you guys have any ideea how to solve this?

Comment: CTRL+F return - 

zero results. Your function doesn't ever return anything! Other problems exist, but this is the one this question is referencing.

Comment: Please add your sample input and expected output.

Comment: Event with `return` keyword it would return zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the function should look something like this:

```
function sum(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      sum += arr[i][j];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr=[[1,2,3,4],5,6,[7,8],9]
var sum=0;
for(var d1 of arr)
  if(d1.length) // undefined if not array||number
    for(var d2 of d1)
      sum+=d2;
  else
    sum+=d1;
// 45
```

Comment: @Dropout: Given array arr, initialize sum to zero, iterate over items in array, if any item doesn't have a length - it's an array (many other ways to check, and assuming we know that's arr's structure) - and iterate over it's items.  Any time an item is encounter, add it's value to the sum.